# Adjective to describe sadness tinged with despair

Tags: word-request, adjectives

What’s an adjective I can use to describe sadness marked by a sense of despair.

> She was suddenly hit with a wave of _____ sadness.

Does “despairing” work? If so, what are some other words that can be used?

Comment: Maybe "hopeless".

Comment: Despairing sadness sounds good.

Answer (score -1):

Overwhelming.

Per [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overwhelming):

> tending or serving to overwhelm
> *overwhelming force
>
> overwhelming evidence*